# Sentiment analysis using wordnet

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet, sentiment-analysis

Given a document, I've to identify an emotion (among joy, sadness, love, fear, anger, surprise) in various parts of the document using method of synonym hops. i.e. by finding distance between words in the document and the seed words for each emotion.

So far I have used nltk wordnet. But the results I have obtained are not satisfactory, path_distance given by wordnet is almost always 0 for fear, anger and surprise emotion. As a result joy or sadness appears to be the closest to most of the words in the document. I am expecting results similar to [this](http://www.seasr.org/documentation/uima-and-seasr/sentiment-tracking-from-uima-data/).

I am not able to find any relevant material on the internet. Is there a well known algorithm or library that has implemented this?

Comment: From where you get this idea about measure distance - maybe start searching from there? Have you watch nlp courses: https://class.coursera.org/nlp/lecture/145 ?